# How to select a specific number of random elements from a set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have a set of 9 elements and I want to write a program which prompts the user for an integer `n`, then displays `n` number of elements selected randomly from my set.

This is what I tried:

```
import random

def main():    
    best_of = eval(input("How many maps do you want to choose? : "))

    choices = ["Arkansas", "Manchuria", "Bengal", "Baja California", "Tibet", "Indonesia", "Cascade Range", "Hudson Bay", "High Plains"]

    random_choice = random.choice(choices)

    for i in range(bes_of):    
        print(random_choice)

main()
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Comment: Why on earth are you using `eval`?

Comment: @thefoureye, I'd say the problem is that `bes_of` is not `best_of`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`random.sample()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) to pick `n` random elements without repetition:

```
sampled = random.sample(choices, best_of)
for choice in sampled:
    print(choice)
```

If all you need is an integer from the user, don't use `eval()`; stick to using `int()` instead:

```
best_of = int(input("How many maps do you want to choose? : "))
```

`eval()` gives you more than you bargained for; it executes *any valid Python expression*, letting the user do anything they want with your program.

Answer (score 1):

You neeed to call the `random.choice()` method inside the for loop so that `n` random elements are printed.

```
import random

def main():    
    best_of = input("How many maps do you want to choose? : ")

    choices = ["Arkansas", "Manchuria", "Bengal", "Baja California", "Tibet", "Indonesia", "Cascade Range", "Hudson Bay", "High Plains"]

    for i in range(int(best_of)):    
        random_choice = random.choice(choices)
        print(random_choice)

main()
```

Comment: Again, why the use of `eval`?

Comment: This can pick the same element more than once.

Comment: You'll find an unpleasant surprise if you test this. :)